# Vue.js Need to hide values if they dont exist

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

How do i get v-hide to work. Below is my example.

All I'm trying to achieve is i want the above to hide if value.photo is empty.

```
<div v-for='value in listPlayers'>

<img v-hide='value.photo.length > 0' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/dummy-copy.gif'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-if` or `v-show` directives and use the negation of your condition :

```
  v-if='!(value.photo.length > 0)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to render the element it is better that you use v-if like this:

```
<div v-for='value in listPlayers'>

   <img v-if='!value.photo.length' src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/dummy-copy.gif'>

</div>
```

You can use v-show also, but with v-show the content will be rendered but not displayed.